# Constraint-Layout alpha7 ConstraintCenterX/Y attribute missing

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I just updated to `com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha7` from `com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha5` but `layout_constraintCenterX_toCenterX` and `layout_constraintCenterY_toCenterY` are missing. did they change their names or if there's an altervative to center two views.

**EDIT** - i did see their release note here http://tools.android.com/recent/constraintlayout-alpha7available they just said it is deprecated. but i want a solution(alternative).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you would like to align B's center with A's center, than you should have B align it's left and right with A's left and right.

Here's an example - `text2` will sit below and to the center of `text1`:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:labelFor="@+id/text2"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/text1"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/text1"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/text1" />
```

Comment: What Joey says. Note that centerX_toCenterX was basically just a shortcut -- internally it was doing left_toLeftOf and right_toRightOf. Same fo centerY.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, its in the release note of ConstraintLayout-alpha 7 [here](http://tools.android.com/recent/constraintlayout-alpha7available)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

simple solution with RTL support

```
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias=".5"
```

without RTL support

```
app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias=".5"
```

you can remove **app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias** if you want

i also reported RTL bug here:

[Link 1](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=220103)

[Link 2](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=222556)